# Proving Product rule with Abstract Algebra Methods

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

Theorem: Let $F$ be a field and $p(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0$ be a polynomial in $F[x]$. The derivative of $p(x)$ is the polynomial

$ D(p(x)) = na_nx^{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-2} + \ldots + a_1. $
Prove that the usual product rule 
$D(p(x)g(x))=p(x)D(g(x))+D(p(x))g(x)$
holds.

Proof: Let $p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0$ and $g(x)=b_kx^k+b_{k-1}x^{k-1} + \ldots + b_0$.

I feel like this can get a little messy, but I don't know how else to go about doing it. Foiling this could get ugly. I'm only a beginner in abstract algebra, so simple help would be beneficial.

Comment: Or you could do what modern mathematicans did eventually-just define a linear map that obeys the product rule i.e. a derivation and simply note the derivative of any differentiable function is a derivation. See how much grief you avoid using abstraction?lol

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If you first prove that $D$ is a linear operator, and that the product rule is (bi)linear in $p$ and $g$, then you only need to verify the identity on a basis.